# how come accuracy_score recognizes the positive label and precision_score does not?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, accuracy

I am executing this code which works perfectly for me:

(I only have 'positive' and 'negative' sentiments):

```
from sklearn import metrics
print('Accuracy:',metrics.accuracy_score(test_sentiments, predicted_sentiments))  
print('Precision:',metrics.precision_score(test_sentiments, predicted_sentiments, pos_label='positive'))
```

My question is: how come ***accuracy_score*** recognizes the positive label and ***precision_score*** does not?

ps: if I execute:

```
print('Precision:',metrics.precision_score(test_sentiments, predicted_sentiments))
```

or

```
print('Accuracy:',metrics.accuracy_score(test_sentiments, predicted_sentiments, pos_label='positive'))
```

They both fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy is symmetric in the naming of positive/negative classes, but precision is not: for accuracy, it doesn't matter which class is "positive."  So `accuracy_score` doesn't have a parameter `pos_label`, and will error if you try to pass that parameter; meanwhile `precision_score` has default `pos_label=1`, so if your labels don't include `1` and you leave the parameter to the default, you'll get an error.